# How to save all unsaved tabs in my notepad++ automatically with some default file names?

Tags: notepad++, tabs

I have lot of open tabs in my notepad++. Few are already saved ones but there are lot of them which are not saved at all. Is there any way to save everything whatever I have in my notepad++ without doing lot of work?

If I click "save all" then it asks me to provide file name for each unsaved ones and I have around 500+ tabs opened in notepad++. It's too much work for me to save all those unsaved ones by clicking on popup window.

For example check header in below screenshot, you will see lot of tabs:

[image: ow t]

Comment: Just curious, why do you have 500+ new files opened in Notepad++? Can you please describe your process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you close Notepad++ all non-saved files are saved in the backup directory, if you have checked

> `Settings > Preferences > Backup > Remember current session for next launch`

- Windows10

```
%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup
```

The filenames are like `new1@date_time`

Comment: I have this enabled, yet there is nothing in that directory.